# Date format changed when printing report in c#

Tags: c#, date, format, report

i developed an application that uses reports, and i have a problem when i attemp to print a report the date format changed to another format on client pc, although it print the date in correct format on my pc, here is two pictures the first from my pc and the other from client pc

my pc

[image]

client pc
[image]

here is the code i used to display a report

```
string DateString = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(DateString, "yyyy/MM/dd", null);
        string DateString2 = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(DateString2, "yyyy/MM/dd", null);

        dailyworkTableAdapter.Fill(this.workingmgmtDataSet1.dailywork,label2.Text,dt,dt2);
        dataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.finalDS.DataTable1,dt,dt2,label2.Text);

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

the date field expresion in report :

```
=Fields!date.Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, the problem was due to report language, after setting the language to be "arabic" , the problem solved.

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The client pc seems to be setup for a different culture. You can force the format of your datetime value like this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string s = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

You can review the culture namespace for more info on dealing with this sort of thing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @A Sal still the same problem, i think the problem from data exchange between mysql query and the report!

Comment: Would you be able to post your code? You might have to force the culture as shown in the link I sent.

Comment: How is the data stored in the database? Are you able to change the format of the stored data?

Comment: date field is of type "date" in database, there is another types tha dbms provide like datetime